# Writing unit test for Deeplink feature on Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, deep-linking

I would like to write a unit test to trigger an app url

**myapp://view/products** which opens up an Activity

and test if the corresponding activity is opened up.

Kindly tell me how do i test such a scenario using unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

For Android deep link testing, you currently have the methods described in Google documentation - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test.

The simplest method consist in using the Search Console "Fetch as Google" and later work on the error reports, fixing what is wrong.

Hope this helps.